# plotting with fading background color

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to produce a plot where the background color is not uniform (e.g. all white) but rather changing as function of the slope of the line that is plotted. A concrete example is:

```
data={{1., 315.457}, {0.997146, 230.976}, {0.988606, 128.556}, {0.974444,74.4523},
      {0.954769, 47.2897}, {0.929731, 32.5402},{0.899519,23.8385}, {0.864364, 18.3407},
      {0.824533, 14.6737}, {0.78033,12.1217}, {0.732091,10.2853}, {0.680182, 8.92909},
      {0.625,7.90752}, {0.566964, 7.12705}, {0.506515, 6.52556}, {0.444114,6.06067},
      {0.380236, 5.70282}, {0.315367, 5.43103}, {0.25,5.23019}, {0.184633, 5.08936}}
```

where I need a white background on the left ($x<0.6$), that fades to red when going to the right ($x=1$).
I am struggling on how to achieve it by programming.

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th5Ho.png)?

Comment: yes! It would be ideal if one could also change the 'slope' of the color gradient.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `DensityPlot[]` to generate the background, and `Lighter[]` + `LogisticSigmoid[]` for coloring:

```
DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 5, 316}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
            ColorFunction -> (Lighter[Red, 1 - LogisticSigmoid[100 (# - 0.65)]] &), 
            Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], ColorData[97, 1]], Point[data]}]
```

[image: fading background]

You can tweak the `100` and `0.65` in `LogisticSigmoid[100 (# - 0.65)]` to adjust the fading.

Comment: can I do this also with ListPlot?

Comment: Yes; remove the part with `Epilog`, and do `Show[DensityPlot[(* stuff *)], ListPlot[(* stuff *)]]`.